# What can hibernate's hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries do?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</property>
```

What can it do?I don't know? Please give an example!

Comment: Have you tried google for a solution? for example it's documentation : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Hibernate Docs - Chapter 3. Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional):

> Forces Hibernate to store data in the second-level cache in a more human-friendly format. e.g. true|false

It specifies whether entries will be written in a readable format or not in the L2 cache. You probably should turn it on if you plan to browse through the cache.

From [Hibernate Docs - Chapter 19. Improving performance](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-sessioncache) :

> To browse the contents of a second-level or query cache region, use the Statistics API: *<code ommited>* You will need to enable statistics and, optionally, force Hibernate to keep the cache entries in a more readable format: 
>   `hibernate.generate_statistics = true` 
>   `hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries = true`

Setting the parameter to `true` will generate some overhead in the [L2 cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache). Seemingly, it cannot be turned off in a clustered environment, because the overhead is needed to rehydrate entities in such a scenario.

You might find the following blog post particulary helpful on this matter: [Hibernate Wars: The Query Cache Strikes Back](http://darren.oldag.net/2009/05/hibernate-wars-query-cache-strikes-back.html), particularly the *Bonus: L2 Cache Reduction* section.

Comment: Good, I will see the post.Thank you!